# Error running selenium webdriver/testng tests headless on a jenkins CI server

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm running Selenium tests using a testNG framework, and an ANT task. The tests run fine on my windows machine..I then deployed it to my Jenkins CI server, and making necessary configurations for running the tests headless:

- installed vnc-server on my server running jenkins (CentOS)
- installed the Xvnc plugin for jenkins and enabled 'run Xvnc during build' in my job config

However I get the below error - any help? I have scoured the web but am unable to find a solution to: "org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console "

```html
[workspace] $ /root/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Ant/bin/ant
Buildfile: /root/.jenkins/jobs/automationFramework/workspace/build.xml

compile:
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/automationFramework/workspace/build.xml:28: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /root/.jenkins/jobs/automationFramework/workspace/test-output

test:
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   /root/.jenkins/jobs/automationFramework/workspace/src/automationFramework/testng.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed via directory addition to Install Location: app-global Item ID: {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed/Upgraded at Install Location: app-global Item ID: {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** ... success, item is compatible
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed via directory addition to Install Location: app-profile Item ID: fxdriver@googlecode.com, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed/Upgraded at Install Location: app-profile Item ID: fxdriver@googlecode.com, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** ... success, item is compatible
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed via directory addition to Install Location: app-system-user Item ID: langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** Item Installed/Upgraded at Install Location: app-system-user Item ID: langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org, attempting to register...
   [testng] *** EM_LOG *** ... success, item is compatible
   [testng] 
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
   [testng]  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
   [testng]  at automationFramework.GoogleTest.testGoogle(Unknown Source)
   [testng]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   [testng]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   [testng]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   [testng]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
   [testng]  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
   [testng]  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
   [testng]  at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
```

selenium version-2.43
firefox - 3.6
Jenkins on centOS - 5.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it usually happens due to incompatible FF and WD versions. So, it makes sense to double check if versions you use are correct.